# How to force a Blackberry device to use GPS positioning in stead of cell triangulation in an HTML5 app?

Tags: html, blackberry, geolocation, gps, triangulation

We are doing some tests with HTML 5 geolocation and our code already works really well on Android and iPhone browsers: we get a continuous update of our precise position on Google maps. You can check our code here: http://93.113.255.166/testHTML5.htm

We also want to make this code work on a Blackberry device, the 9780 Bold with Blackberry 6.0 O.S., but it doesn't work as we would like. The position you get is a rough one, probably calculated through cell triangulation, and there is no precise position displayed. The position is most of the time some 300-400m wrong.

It's clear that the GPS positioning of the phone isn't used, because when you try the native Blackberry positioning apps, you get a very precise position.

We also use the enableHighAccuracy: true attribute in the code: this helps for the iPhone and Android browsers, but not for Blackberry browsers.

So it seems that we are unable to force the device to use the GPS. Is there anybody who could help us? Thanks!

Kristof

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help, but I have a problem using geolocation with Blackberry os6 using 3G; it works as designed (cell triangle if GPS hasn't fix) using GPRS, 3G with WiFi, GPRS with WiFi, but NOT using 3G alone.

My carrier is Vodafone Italy, but I read other people using os6 have the same problem. Obviously it works when GPS has fixed.

Reading around it seems it is a carrier problem, not a BB firmware problem, but I haven't any way to test roaming at the moment.

Looking at the BB log it seems it switches from BIS to wap when asking position, but then it is not able to reconnect BIS like os5 does (try with Google Maps on BB).

Comment: Hi Paolo, sorry for my late answer (I was on holiday). I believe you are right and that it has something to do with switching from BIS to WAP and back. I have the same problem here on my operator. That's really a pitty. Thanks! Kristof

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. No matter if I set `enablehighaccuracy` to true of false, the phone always gives rough location. But GPS tool gives accuracy results.

A temporary way to solve this is to disable cell connection for couple of minutes. Then test your site again. If it can get accurate location, you can turn cell connection back on and the location will always be accurate till next reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's of course not an ideal solution for customers to turn of their connection, but I will try it in my tests. Thanks, Kristof